# How can the Vedas be eternal when it has authored verses?

Tags: vedas, apaurusheyatva

How can the Vedas be authorless when it has authored speech? For example in the [Chandogya Upanishad](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe01/sbe01167.htm):

> The Devas (gods) and Asuras (demons) both heard these words, and **said: 'Well, let us search for that Self by which, if one has searched it out, all worlds and all desires are obtained.'** **Thus saying** Indra went from the Devas, Virokana from the Asuras, and both, without having communicated with each other, approached Pragâpati, holding fuel in their hands, as is the custom for pupils approaching their master. They dwelt there as pupils for thirty-two years. **Then Pragâpati asked them:** 'For what purpose have you both dwelt here?'

The Upanishads are full of conversations like this. So how can it be said that the Vedas are eternal when it consists of authored speech?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118698/discussion-on-question-by-ikshvaku-how-can-the-vedas-be-eternal-when-it-has-auth).

Answer (score 2):

These conversations in the vedas are not real. These conversations are just a story to teach the nature of the Self and Self-knowledge.

The below commentary on this part of Chhandogya Upanishad, is based on Shankara bhashya.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english/d/doc239454.html

> **Again and again the Upaniṣads glorify Self-knowledge, but what is the nature of the Self, and how do we attain that knowledge? Here the Upaniṣad begins a story to answer this.** Once Prajāpati, the creator, decided to teach people about the Self. He described the Self as apahata-pāpmā, free from sins, or blemishes (pāpa)—that is to say, it is pure. Vijara—it never ages, or decays. Vimṛtyu—it is free from death.

All similar conversations are either stories or allegories that are intended to teach about either brahman or details of yagna etc. These are not to be considered as real conversations.

Comment: Yeah but the Vedanta school considers them real. The Purva Mimamsa school considers them to be fake stories though. So if we consider them real, how can the eternity of the Veda be maintained?

Comment: @Ikshvaku The advaita-vedAnta school does not consider these as real stories. Shankara says this is a eulogy of Knowledge.

Comment: Does he make a stronger statement anywhere else?

Comment: @Ikshvaku "stronger statement" means?

Comment: more literal statement

Comment: @Ikshvaku Conversation between yagnavalkya and maitreyi in brihadaranyaka upanishad is also considered a story by Shankara. Accounts of creation are also considered as stories by Shankara.

Comment: ok but stories can be real. Story doesn't mean fake story, story just means narrative.

Comment: see Adi shankara denies the existence of the world for him everything inclding sum total of veda is unreal because if you accept reallity of veda than need to accept the reality of the world because those entities described in the vedas become real.. that is point of view shankara.. In the sum total existence of God is also denied because veda is unreal means God meantioned in Vedas are unreal too.. its ends up in pure buddhist nillist view of the world this what sriman madhvacharya told,that Advaita is another name buddhist philiosophy by name prachana buddha

Comment: @PrasannaR With all due respect, dvaita AchAryas have misinterpreted both Shruti as well as advaita-vedAnta. Upanishads themselves say that in the state of deep sleep, vedas are no vedas, what to mention of the state of liberation? Advaita vedAnta never said brahman is unreal. Brahman is the only reality in advaita. To suggest otherwise is incorrect. Not only advaita, even purva mimamsa held that many things in vedas are arthavAda.

Comment: saw that whole of shankara premise is wrong..  Brahma is the only reality, World is illusion along with veda.. what is it mean.. is it not buddhist philosophy of declaring veda as appramana..  Once one declares veda appramana the sum total of gods specified in vedas are Aapprama..or non existence

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have scriptural reference, so I'll repeat what we discussed in comments earlier based on purely logical stance)

--The hidden premise in your question --
How can Vedas be Apaurusheya **IF** they contain authored conversations ?
--seems to be that--
Vedas can be Apaurusheya IF THEY DO NOT contain authored conversations.

Vedas : "Prajapati said 'Search for Brahman/Atman'"
Vedas : "Brahma created worlds as it was before (Yatha Purvam Akalpayat)"

You consider the 1st statement to be 'authored speech' i.e. **dependent** on a person/time/place - hence, man-made, hence against the doctrine of having no creator (Apaurusheya).

You consider the 2nd statement as possibly **independent**, because Brahma is a post inhabited by different Jivas in each kalpa, hence the same cycle of creation repeats, hence not against the doctrine of Apaurusheya.

My stance is to establish an equivalence between these two.

The rishis/devas/asuras/indra/prajapati - could be posts too. The exact same conversations could happen in every kalpa, just as the exact same creation happens in every kalpa.

Or - Brahma could be as mortal as the authors of those conversations. There is no need to grant special status to the Jiva Brahma, if you are not granting it to the speakers.

Any statement in Vedas refers to some being or thing or action in the universe.
If Vedas refer to a tree (a Jiva), or Brahma (a Jiva), or Prajapati (a Jiva), or a tree listening to Vedas (an action by a Jiva), or Brahma creating the world (an action by a Jiva), or Prajapati giving some advice (an action by a Jiva) - I do not see any difference.

How can Vedas be Apaurusheya IF they contain *anything that exists in this universe* ?

Comment: "The exact same conversations could happen in every kalpa, just as the exact same creation happens in every kalpa." - This just means the vedas are created every kalpa....

Comment: @Ikshvaku - Of course creation happens every kalpa. A tree is created every kalpa. It doesn't mean it was created from nothing. Suksha form always exists. Same for Vedas.

Comment: So then vedas are dependent on human speech every kalpa. That goes against what is traditionally said that the mantras are just passed down from person to person in an eternal cycle.

Comment: No Vedas are not dependent on human speech. Human speech is dependent on Vedas

Comment: I just cited several verses from vedas where people said things from their own experiences, etc. So they did not say those things based on the vedas. What they said forms the basis of the vedas.

Comment: We're back to same discussion. A person saying "I realized Brahman" is - a Jiva creating a Shabda. Brahma creating a rock is - a Jiva creating a Prithvi. Both refer to a Jiva doing something. You already agree there is no difference between the two. I think your assumption stems from the phrase 'from their own experience' - what if every rishi who says that has the exact same experience and says the exact same statement in every kalpa? It doesn't mean Vedas are created every Kalpa, It just means Humans repeat the same thing every kalpa. And what they repeat is called Vedas.

Comment: But no one is claiming that the universe, rocks, tree, etc. are eternal. People are claiming that the Vedic verses are eternal and not dependent on human cognition. But the Vedas themselves say that the Verses are not eternal and are dependent on human experience. When someone speaks from their experience, then the statements are dependent on human experience. And people in the Vedas speak from their experience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119023/discussion-between-ram-and-ikshvaku).